# TypeScript type declarations for .pdf file

Tags: typescript, pdf, types

I am new to TypeScript and I am simply trying to create a type definition for a pdf file and cannot locate any resources on how to do so. I am getting this warning where I import the file `"Cannot find module <file_name.pdf> or its corresponding type declarations."`

I would like to avoid changing my `tsconfig.json` file.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do with binary pdf contents?

Comment: @zerkms Nothing, I just simply need to add an any type to the file such that this warning goes away.

Comment: `declare module '*.pdf';` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using `declare module '*.pdf';` inside of `global.d.ts` file inside of an "included" directory like this answer https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8021.

Answer (score 23):

Rather than modifying the NPM package you can simply modify the tsconfig.js to add a custom typing, which is considerably more future-proof than the accepted solution.

Create the typings file in your src directory named: types.d.ts (or whatever). Insert:

```
declare module "*.pdf";
```

add this to your tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"]
 ....
 }
```